# Using Unique without namespace declaration

Tags: xsd

Can anyone explain why a unique identity constraint on an eleement would not work unless the elements are namespace prefixed? This leads me to beleive that unique constraints can only be applied to gloabbly defined elements. I am not sure why a unique constratint couldnt be put on a locally defiened element. In my sample schema below, i have a unique constraint defined on Writer.name which works fine. I also defined one on Test.name which does not work unless I make Test and its chiled name, global elements.

```
<schema targetNamespace="http://www.amica.com/dev_v1/Test" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.amica.com/dev_v1/Test" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <element name="MyMusic">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="Song" type="tns:SongType"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
    <complexType name="SongType">
        <sequence>
            <element ref="tns:Artists"/>
            <element ref="tns:Writers"/>
            <element name="Tests">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="Test" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <complexType>
                                <sequence>
                                    <element name="name"/>
                                </sequence>
                            </complexType>
                        </element>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
                <unique name="UniqueTestName">
                    <selector xpath="Test"/>
                    <field xpath="name"/>
                </unique>
            </element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <element name="Artist">
        <complexType>
            <simpleContent>
                <extension base="string">
                    <attribute name="aID" use="required">
                        <simpleType>
                            <restriction base="string"/>
                        </simpleType>
                    </attribute>
                </extension>
            </simpleContent>
        </complexType>
    </element>
    <element name="Writer">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element ref="tns:name"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
    <element name="Artists">
        <annotation>
            <documentation>Test unique constraint on an attrbute</documentation>
        </annotation>
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element ref="tns:Artist" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <unique name="UniqueArtistKey">
            <selector xpath="tns:Artist"/>
            <field xpath="@aID"/>
        </unique>
    </element>
    <element name="Writers">
        <annotation>
            <documentation>Test unique constraint on an element</documentation>
        </annotation>
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element ref="tns:Writer" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <unique name="UniqueWriterName">
            <selector xpath="tns:Writer"/>
            <field xpath="tns:name"/>
        </unique>
    </element>
    <element name="name" type="string"/>
</schema>
```

Comment: It works for me - once I specify the type of name: '<element name="name" type="string"/>'. I am using Visual Studio 2010 XML editor built-in XSD validation.